# Selenium webdriver Python on ubuntu SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to create a webdriver object in python3.6/selenium3.141.0/Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Lightsail Amazon Linux), but when I call the webdriver.Chrome() object, it raises an exception. The code works when I ran it locally using windows (I only have to change the chromedriver to the windows version). The chromedriver is located in /usr/bin/chromedriver and my user has permission to execute it.

========================================================

My code is a web app using Flask and running on gunicorn server and it uses the python threading package.

Thanks in advance!

---

Chromedriver and Chrome versions installed on Ubuntu:
Chromedriver (chromedriver_linux64.zip from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=76.0.3809.126/)

Command: chromedriver -v  ; I get its version:
ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126 (d80a294506b4c9d18015e755cee48f953ddc3f2f-refs/branch-heads/380
9@{#1024})

command: google-chrome-stable -version ; I get its version:
Google Chrome 76.0.3809.132

according to this site, these are the correct/compatible versions for the 76 release:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
Current Releases
If you are using Chrome version 77, please download ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40
If you are using Chrome version 76, please download ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126
If you are using Chrome version 75, please download ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.140
For older version of Chrome, please see below for the version of ChromeDriver that supports it.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, UnexpectedAlertPresentException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import chromedriver_binary

##...(there is another function before to create folders)

def funcCX():
   chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
   driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

#

These are the commands that I used to install chrome and chromedriver:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add 
echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list

sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
google-chrome-stable -version

sudo apt-get install -y unzip xvfb libxi6 libgconf-2-4

wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.126/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip

sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver
chromedriver -v
```

This is the error message that appears:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 
603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 
387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 
383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/AttCx1/pesquisas.py", line 127, in funcCiweb
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)

  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriv
er.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriv
er.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriv
er.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriv
er.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_
connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_
connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 72, in 
request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 150, in
 request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 326, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 368, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/home/ubuntu/att-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

This message repeats more two times because of another two threads that try to create others webdriver objects using the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should add the next line to your [ChromeDriver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.options) initialization routine

```
 chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
```

as this is absolutely required when you're running Chrome as the [root user](https://geek-university.com/linux/root-account/)

References:

- [Chromium Issue 638180](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=638180)
- [How to Disable Chrome Sandbox](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-disable-chrome-sandbox)
- [How to use Jenkins pipeline to launch Selenium tests](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/jenkins-pipeline-selenium/)